# php url without extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My subject is different from the deprecated one, all I need is to get a string as URL without showing the PHP filename.
I have items to click and to go to edit.php page
I am trying to get a clicked string as URL.

e.g. if I click 'abc' , I want to go to the page edit.php and the browser displays :

```
http://localhost/abc
```

not to

```
http://localhost/edit.php?item=abc
```

It's something like the routing in Symfony.

Comment: you need to use htaccess.

Comment: You may also need to include some kind of action in the url as well for example `/edit/abc` would take you to `edit.php?item=abc` while `/abc` might tack you to `show.php?item=abc`. In any event if you have more than a couple types of actions you are probably going to want to use a router on the PHP side instead of jsut htaccess only. Depending on how far along on your poject you are you might jsut want to use a micro framework like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) or [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/). It will most likely save you time and headache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example .htaccess file for your VERY SPECIFIC example above:

```
# turn on rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# check that the request isn't actually a real file (e.g. an image)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# redirect requests for BLAH to /edit.php?item=BLAH
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /edit.php?item=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here are the docs you need for anything else http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html